# Add Resources and Rooms to google calendar event Python API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I’m in the process of developing a small Python application to automatically add events to a shared Google Calendar. I'm using Google Cloud APIs and I’m able to create, delete and modify almost all the field. The only parameter I need but I’m not able to assign is Resources and Rooms [image: Highlighted the field I’m referring to]

I do not find any guide or explanation on haw to manipulate this parameter.
Did anyone manage to do that using python?

Thanks.

I've tried to assign the field:

```
'attendees': [{'email': 'pippo@gmail.com'}}
```

Without any success.
I'm not abel to find the correct parameter to write to tell that the resource PIPPO is assigned to a specific event.